# Swift Combine return result of first future after evaluation of second

Tags: swift, combine

I have the following situation:

2 futures, one returns a value I am interested in, the other does some operations and returns void. The 2 are not related to each other (so the code should not be mixed), but both need to be executed in the right order in the application logic.

What I want to do is subscribe to a publisher that does the following:

- future one executes and gives a value
- future two executes and returns nothing
- the subscriber receives the value of future one after the execution of future two.

Here is a small code example that does not compile, that shows what I would like to achieve:

```
import Combine


func voidFuture() -> Future<Void, Error> {
    return Future<Void, Error> { promise in
        promise(.success(()))
    }
}

func intFuture() -> Future<Int, Error> {
    return Future<Int, Error> { promise in
        promise(.success(1))
    }
}

  

func combinedFuture() -> AnyPublisher<Int, Error> {
    var intValue: Int!

    return intFuture().flatMap { result in
        intValue = result
        return voidFuture()
    }.flatMap{ _ in
        return CurrentValueSubject(intValue).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()

combinedFuture()
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { _ in }, receiveValue: { val in print(val)})
    .store(in: &subscriptions)
```

Comment: So what order should the Futures execute in? Do you want `intFuture` to execute first and then `voidFuture` or the other way around? From your description I've got the feeling you want `voidFuture` to execute first. Bear in mind that your publishers should not be doing side effects (which I get the feeling they are doing considering the fact that you need a publisher that takes no input arguments and emits no values to be executed after another publisher). Side effects make functions non-pure and combine is a functional reactive framework, so all publishers should be pure functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `.map` the `Void` result of the second publisher (`voidFuture`) back to the result of the first publisher (`intFuture`), which is what the `.flatMap` would emit:

```
func combinedFuture() -> AnyPublisher<Int, Error> {
    intFuture().flatMap { result in
        voidFuture().map { _ in result }
    }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Comment: This works. The map <-> flatMap thing is still giving me headaches tbh. Still having a hard time understanding when to use which one.

Comment: @JorisMans, `.map` operator takes an emitted value from an upstream publisher and maps it to another value. `.flatMap` takes an emitted value, and creates a publisher - then emits value(s) of that publisher. In this case, `flatMap` creates a `voidPublisher().map {...}`, which is a publisher that emits an `Int` value following a void value

Comment: Yes, that's also the text I remembered, but it's still hard to apply it in practice. Like in the code here above, why can't flatMap be used to return a new publisher that emits that result value? example: voidFuture().flatMap { _ in CurrentValueSubject(result) } or something like that.

Comment: @JorisMans, technically you can - Swift just fails to infers types, so you'd need to be more explicit about the return value of each `flatMap`, ie. `.flatMap { _ -> AnyPublisher<Int, Error> in .... }`. You're also not really using the `CurrentValueSubject` in any meaningful way - you can just use the `Just(intValue).setFailureType(to: Error.self)`. It's just unnecessarily convoluted, since you already have the value you want to return inside the first `.flatMap`, so no need to go via a local variable route